# second degree congruence solution $ f(x) \equiv 0 \ ( \text{mod} \ 2) $

Tags: number-theory

How could I solve, apart from brute force, the congruence

$$ \frac{x(x-1)}{2} \equiv 0\ ( \text{mod} \ 2) \ ? $$

I mean, for what values of $y$ has the polynomial $ x(x-1)=2y $ only integer solutions and even for example $ x=f(y) $ is an EVEN number ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $4\mid xy,$ then either $4\mid x,$ or $4\mid y,$ or $2$ divides both $x$ and $y.$
Thus, for $x(x-1)/2$ to be even, there are two possibilities:
$$\begin{cases}x\equiv0\pmod4\\x-1\equiv0\pmod4\end{cases}.$$
Notice that it is impossible that both $x$ and $x-1$ are even, hence the above two cases are all cases.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

$y=8n^2-2n$ will yield all possible solutions for $2y=x(x-1)$ when $y$ must be even.